# Volume Absorption not darkening

Tags: rendering, materials, objects, color, volumetrics

[image: ios:1.33 ; colour 'v' value: 0.963 ; density: 782.7]

I don't understand why my "coffee" still looks like water. What can I change to make the coffee darker but still realistic? I couldn't post my screenshot, so please let me know anything I could fix and I'll explain my settings.

Comment: Hello :). Please add an image of your material setup. Without that it's just guessing.

Comment: Or watch the "tutorial" again, and see what the person is doing to make the material...